# Recover HttpHeader on Flex

Tags: apache-flex, http-headers

Is it possible to recover the HttpHeader information from a flex Client?

I want to do the following:

- User download the flex client from a web site
- In each communication flex client catch the HttpHeader information in order to change (If it is necessary) the host information to be connected (For example in a HA configuration)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ResultEvent` has a headers field. The user will download the flex client, then if you have your application run any kind of service (HTTPService, WebService, etc), it will return a ResultEvent. You can get the headers from that event.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try: [as3httpclientlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/)